# Проблема при работе с потоками c++

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Есть задание: В одномерном массиве найти максимум среди нечетных чисел. Я набросал данный код на 4 потока:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
const int COUNT = 110;
const int MAX_NTHREAD = 4;
mutex Mutex;
void init_array(int arr[])
{
    srand(GetTickCount());
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand() % 100;
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }


}

void search(int arr[], int start, int finish, int& result)
{
    int local_result = 0;
    int max = arr[0];
    for (int i = start; i < finish; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] % 2 != 0)
        {
            if (arr[i] > max)
            {
                local_result = arr[i];
            }
        }
    }
    lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(Mutex);
    result = local_result;
    cout << this_thread::get_id() << ": " << result <<
        endl;

    
}
int search_threads(int arr[])
{
    unsigned int const min_block_size = 25;
    unsigned int const max_threads =
        (COUNT + min_block_size - 1) / min_block_size;
    unsigned int const hardware_threads =
        thread::hardware_concurrency();
    unsigned int const count_threads =
        min(hardware_threads != 0 ?
            hardware_threads : 2, max_threads);
    int block_size = COUNT / count_threads;
    int result= 0;
    vector<thread> threads(count_threads - 1);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<count_threads - 1; i++)
        threads[i] = thread(search, arr, block_size*i,
            block_size*(i + 1), ref(result));
    search(arr, block_size*(count_threads - 1), COUNT, result);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<count_threads - 1; i++)
        threads[i].join();
    return result;
}
int main()
{
    int a[COUNT];
    init_array(a);
    cout << "Result = " << search_threads(a) << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Но он работает не совсем верно: выводит не максимальное число. Прошу подсказать, в чем ошибка и объяснить, как ее исправить.

Answer (score 2):

Логично, все потоки используют переменную result для записи результата. Кто последний запишет, тот и выиграл. Что делать? сделать для каждого потока свою переменную (можно даже массив сделать) и потом в конце в этом массиве найти максимум.  Либо подумать и переделать логику под мютексом. Правда нужен будет ещё флажок, что максимум был найден хотя бы первый раз.

Comment: Я не автор вопроса, но спасибо сказать хочу! Уважаемый KoVadim, меня всегда восхижает способность в нескольких строках изложить суть.